# sql aggregation - COUNT(*), SUM(), AVG() and GROUP BY as keywords

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

Learning SQL, having difficulties wrapping my head around aggregation. Every time, I try to code on POSTGRESQL, it seems like it never work.

How do you combine COUNT(*), SUM(), AVG() and GROUP BY as keywords?

Example: List region, number of countries, total area, and average area per country for all regions of the world. 
!https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/499664226491564038/501053634864349204/unknown.png[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUVuJ.png)

Comment: Please add some sample table data to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example. We've got a table called `employee`:

```
create table employee as
  select 1 as id, 'Bob' as name, 1000000 as salary, 'IT' as department union all
  select 2, 'John', 100000, 'IT' union all
  select 3, 'Tom', 10000, 'IT' union all
  select 4, 'Ann', 2000000, 'HR' union all
  select 5, 'Tony', 200000, 'HR' union all
  select 6, 'Mary', 20000, 'HR'
```

and we want to know the number of employees and the total and average salary in each department. We can get this with:

```
SELECT department, COUNT(*), SUM(SALARY), AVG(SALARY)
  FROM employee
  GROUP BY department
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=f7621207e5cd178bfc6301f211ba7c35)